# How to extract emails with command line?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I'm using the following command to extract emails from a file:

```
perl -ne'if(/[\w\.\-\_]+@([\w\-\_]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}/g){print "$&\n"}' database.sql
```

What do I need to change to make this print the results to a new file?

Or if you have a better solution via command line to extract all emails, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following option that uses [Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Address-1.898/lib/Email/Address.pm) will be helpful:

```
perl -MEmail::Address -ne 'print "@a\n" if @a = Email::Address->parse($_)' inFile >outFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the output to a file like so:

```
perl -ne'if(/[\w\.\-\_]+@([\w\-\_]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}/g){print "$&\n"}' database.sql > somefile
```